# Polymer/web components <app-router> Cannot GET/<route>

Tags: routes, polymer, web-component

I'm using Polymer for an app and using Erik Ringsmuth's [app-router](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router) for routing. The code is as follows:

In index.html:

```
<app-router mode="pushstate">
  <app-route path="/" import="/elements/login-page/login-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/dash" import="/elements/dash-page/dash-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/new" import="/elements/newapp-page/newapp-page.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="*" import="/elements/dash-page/dash-page.html"></app-route>
</app-router>
```

In login-page.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="login-page" attributes="">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login-page.css">
    <section vertical layout center-center>
      <h1>Login with:</h1>
      <fire-login provider="github"></fire-login>
      <fire-login provider="facebook"></fire-login>
    </section>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

The other pages are similar. Everything works fine out of the box but when I refresh any of the pages I get a `Cannot GET /dash` or `Cannot GET /new`. Going back to the root path and refreshing gets everything going again.

I can't figure out why refreshing doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting more magic from this component than it could provide :)

The requests are going to HTTP server, not directly to the `<app-router>` component. You are using HTML5 `pushState` way of handling routes. That said, when you specify `/new` as new path, the component shows the desired import *and substitutes the `location.href` with `http://youserver/new`*. On the other hand, when you press `F5`, *the browser is being redirected to `http://youserver/new`*. Sounds like different actions, right?

So, the request to `http://youserver/new` is being handled by your web server and since there is no such page, you get `404`.

You have two options here:

- teach your HTTP server to handle `/new` as `your_router_page.html` with `mod_rewrite` or like;
- specify the proper path in `<app-route>`s.

The component-way (IMHO) is to specify the proper path:

```
<app-route path="/my-router.html?/dash"></app-route>
```

Or even better get stuck to hash-like navigation, since it works out of the box and requires no specific route handling at all. The `pushState` is more like to handle redirects to outside of the current component handler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up switching to hash URLs and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much.